# Force legacy API clients to use new AWS API Gateway with API Key header

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-key, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway

We have large API moved to an AWS API Gateway to get better monitoring and use of API Key. Now we need get developers to use that Gateway endpoint instead of an old endpoint. Of course this transition should be done with sufficient time and starting from a new API clients.
First simple thought I have in mind is some kind of a new header Gateway adds to requests forwarded via it. And our backend should be coded to accept requests only with that gateway hashed header information.
Do you have solutions to move API  users from old endpoint to API Gateway endpoint with required API Key?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a Lambda Authorizer in the new API to inspect the request header and Deny or Allow the request based in the payload:

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

Comment: Thank for your answer. Your solution doesn't work when client requets API past the gateway. Problem is that we haven't had any gateway before. Only direct connection from client to the backend endpoint. Now when we have added a new proxy gateway we would like to transfer all the traffic to go through that gateway instead of old direct requests to API. I guess only way is to change our API to allow only requests which origins from that gateway.

Comment: Yes, that is what you explicitly said in your question. You must change the flow to "client -> api gateway -> old api". With custom authorizers, you can inject any custom auth you need (custom headers, jwt or payload signing). Your old API must block any other request and accept requests with only the defined logic. Hence, it is a way to move users from old api to new one.